# JQgrid 'Grid can not be used in this (quirks) mode' IE 9

Tags: html, jsp, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

I have a jsp that creates JQgrid. When i try to open it in IE9, iget the error that 'Grid can not be used in this (quirks) mode'

I have tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

but it does not work. My doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

i have also tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

but it does not work.

Comment: can you confirm whether it works or not in other IE versions? eg IE8, IE10, IE11? Also, if you open the F12 dev tools, what does the browser mode actually show as? ie is it *actually* in quirks mode, or is it jqgrid that is misreporting it?

Comment: thanks Spudley. i did not check for other versions, but the dev tools shows that Browser Mode : IE 9 Document Mode IE 9. Now here is the really crazy part. i was developing the webpage in Eclipse. Thats where the quirks mode error shows up. However, when i load the same page in a BROWSER, there is no error ! the page and the grid load just fine !

Answer (score 1):

With just the information given, I agree with you that IE should not be going into quirks mode.

There are a few other things that might be triggering it; it's not possible to be certain with the information given, but the most likely thing I can think of is white space before the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

Older IE versions have a bug whereby if there is white space in the page before the doctype - even just a new line character - it causes IE to see the doctype as invalid. This in turn kicks it into quirks mode.